# R - replace zero values by average of non-zero ones for fixed categories

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I am given a dataset of the following form

```
year<-rep(c(1990:1999),each=10) 
age<-rep(50:59, 10)
cat1<-rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),each=100)
value<-rnorm(10*10*5)
value[c(3,51,100,340,441)]<-0
df<-data.frame(year,age,cat1,value)

  year age  cat1     value
1 1990  50    A -0.7941799
2 1990  51    A  0.1592270
3 1990  52    A  0.0000000
4 1990  53    A  1.9222384  
5 1990  54    A  0.3922259
6 1990  55    A -1.2671957
```

I now would like to replace any zeroes in the "value" column by the average over the column "cat1" of the non-zero entries of "value" for the corresponding year and age. For example, for year 1990, age 52 the enty for cat1=A is zero, this should be replaced by average of the non-zero entries of the remaining categories for this specific year and age.
As we have

```
df[df$year==1990 & df$age==52,]
    year age  cat1     value
3   1990  52    A  0.0000000
103 1990  52    B -1.1325446
203 1990  52    C -1.6136773  
303 1990  52    D  0.5724360
403 1990  52    E  0.2795241
```

we would replace the entry 0 by

```
sum(df[df$year==1990 & df$age==52,4])/4
[1] -0.4735654
```

Is there a nice and clean way to this generally?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[value==0, value := NA,]
df[, value := replace(value, is.na(value), mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)) , by = .(year, age)]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe 99,9% of operations with tables can be decomposed into basic fast and optimized: split, concatenation(in case of numeric: sum, multiplication etc), filter, sort, join.

Here left_join from dplyr is your way to go. 
Just create another dataframe filtered from zeroes and aggregated over **value** with proper grouping. Then substitute zeroes with values from new joined column.